# Shared Log Destination for App and Service

Tags: c#, logging, service, log4net

I'm adding logging (log4net) to an application that has a companion service. The application accepts information regarding how the service will run, creates the service, and controls starting and stopping it.

Because the service can run under a different, non-admin user account, I'm having trouble find a log destination that allows both processes to write to the same log file or folder.

I've tried various locations, but they fall into two categories:

1. They are restricted from non-admin users, for example the app exe location in `Program Files`.
2. They provide write access only for the credentials used to run the management app. This applies to the `AppData` folders for obvious reasons, but also the `CommonApplicationData` folder which gives rights to the creator/owner.

Comment: So I take it this is a problem using an installer, as otherwise you could set the permissons to whatever you want? If so, what installer are you using?

Comment: @stuartd I know I can set permissions at install or at runtime, but I'd like to avoid the complication and simply write to a location where everyone just has write access. Are you saying there is no such place?

Comment: I don't think there is.